# Why can't I access Custom Taxonomy metadata?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'm trying to access Custom Taxonomy metadata for all my custom taxonomy terms. The metadata is stored in options like so:

```
$t_id = $term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
    $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
    foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
        if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
            $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
        }
    }
    // Save the option array.
    update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
```

In my attempt to get at each metadata field, I've written the following code, but my array `$term_meta` is completely empty. Echoing `$t_id` returns all the IDs  successfully, however.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'hhie_artists';
$args = array(
'hide_empty' => 0
);
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $empty_terms[] = $term;
    $t_id = $term->term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( 'taxonomy_' . $t_id );
    print_r( $term_meta );
    echo $t_id;
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

As an example, one of the keys in the array would be `$term_meta['release_date_meta']`
**EDIT:** Using this on a page template for testing purposes.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code block suggests you're saving your data into a options field named `taxonomy_$t_id`, but you're trying to get an option named `taxonomy_123` in your second code, or whatever the actual term ID is. So you probably getting a return with the value `false`, which would be the default for [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option). Have you debugged this? Are you sure you have the meta data saved like you want it to be?

```
// term ID
$t_id = $term->term_id;
// overly long variable name for the option for demonstration purposes
$term_meta_data_options_name = 'taxonomy_' . $t_id;

// get option with the defined term meta data options name
$term_meta = get_option( $term_meta_data_options_name );

// add/update option with the defined term meta data options name
update_option( $term_meta_data_options_name );
```

Comment: Expanding upon this, check your `wp_options` table to see what data is being saved and what the names are.